# How can I accomplish this logical exclusion of certain records?

Tags: mongodb

Rewritten for clarity,
I need to exclude any records where the key is greater than 2 unfortunately I cant bail out on `.find` for `aggregate` because then I lose my language specific features

i've already tried nesting `$ne` in each field but currently not getting what I'm looking to accomplish

Example Data:

```json
[
  { status: 'draft', key: 1, ... },
  { status: 'terminated', key: 2, ... },
  { status: 'terminated', key: 3, ... },
  ...
]
```

Javascript

```js
const query = {
  $and: [
    { status: { $ne: 'terminated' }, key: { $lte: 2 } }
  ]
}

db.getCollection('forecasts').find(query)
```

Desired Output

```json
[
  { status: 'draft', key: 1, ... },
  { status: 'terminated', key: 3, ... },
]
```

Got

```json
[
  { status: 'draft', key: 1, ... }
]
```

This throws an error (elasticsearch supports this sort of logic):

```js
db.getCollection('forecasts').find({
    $and: [{
      $not: { status: 'terminated', key: { $gt: 2 } }
    }]   
})
```

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $not. If you have a field name that starts with a '$' symbol, consider using $getField or $setField.",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

if it was raw javascript it would be done in the following way

```js
const collection = [
  { status: 'draft', key: 1 },
  { status: 'terminated', key: 2 },
  { status: 'terminated', key: 3 }
]

const response = collection.filter(doc => {
  let include = true
  if (doc.status === 'terminated' && doc.key <= 2) include = false
  return include
})

console.log(response)
// => [ { status: 'draft', key: 1 }, { status: 'terminated', key: 3 } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (doc.status === 'terminated' && doc.key <= 2) include = false` means the white part, so basically you want the yellow part.

[image]

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    { status: { $ne: "terminated" } },
    { key: { $gt: 2 } }
  ]
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xa7DLeXRz0I)